# Crystal report viewer Print and Preview then Print produce different output

Tags: crystal-reports, reportviewer

I use Crystal Report Basic to create report for my application, my problem is when I view my report in report viewer and click print (without preview) it produce different output (page margin is different) as I preview and print the same report.

I want to know how to solving this problem?

Comment: What do you mean - a different output? Check the report filename please.

Comment: Yes it produce different margin.

Answer (score 0):

I found this out:
The crystal report viewer resets to default margins when you print the report to the actual printer.
To counteract this i did this in my code. It manually sets the margins. Set them to what you need yourself.
The "YourReportDocument" is the crystal report document i instantiated and set as the CrystalReportViewer reportsource

```
CrystalDecisions.Shared.PageMargins margin = new CrystalDecisions.Shared.PageMargins();
margin.leftMargin = 0;
margin.rightMargin = 0;
margin.topMargin = 0;
margin.bottomMargin = 292;
yourReportDocument.PrintOptions.ApplyPageMargins(margin);
```

If you have subreports in the report you might need to open the report and to into those subreports and tinker with the margins, because I'm not sure the above code makes the subreports change.